# How to change an Oracle table schema on live web application without restarting it?

Tags: c#, datatable, oracle11g, schema

I have a quite specific question, for a quite specific problem. My dev environment is pretty simple : an Oracle 11g database, C# web application (with ASP).

To connect to my database, I use the OracleManagedDataAccess nuget package and it worked fine until last month. I was able to add columns on my tables without any problem, but now, it returns an exception : index out of range when loading my DataReader into a DataTable.

```
string connectionString = "myConnectionStringToTheDB";
string requete = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";

using (var connexion = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    connexion.Open();

    using (var commande = new OracleCommand(requete, connexion))
    using (var dr = commande.ExecuteReader())
    using (var datatable = new DataTable())
    {
        datatable.Load(dr); // => crashes here
        foreach (DataRow row in datatable.Rows)
        {
            var campagne = GetFromDataReader<Campagne>(row, connectionString);
            campagne.CodeSource = row["CODE_SOURCE"].ToString();
            result.Add(campagne);
        }
    }
}
```

This code works when the app is running, no problem. Then I add a column to my table. Then I run this code again, and NOPE... I have to stop and restart the app (on IIS) to get it running fine.

The fact is that when my query includes a '*', it crashes. If I list all the columns of my table, it works.
This problem suddenly occured with no reason and it is really annoying as I need to add columns to my table even when there are users connected to the app. These newly added columns won't be used until the restart of the program of course...

Do you know how to solve this problem ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

After a few tries, I figured out what happened.
The error came from my version of the OracleManagedDataAccess DLL.
Versions post 18.6 automatically includes Request and Metadata Pooling.

-I had to rollback from 19.1 to 18.6

-I added => "Metadata Pooling=false;Statement Cache Purge=true;" to my connection string, and now it works fine again.

So I won't be able to update this DLL any further now. Well, anyway...